# Goodreads type of fb posts through facebook graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

[image]

Here is the screenshot of the post goodreads publishes to user's feed.

The closest I have seen on the fb graph api is

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/me/feed",
    "POST",
    {
        "message": "This is a test message"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

But this only posts a message text. How do I get my fb app to post a similar post as the one like goodreads which contains an image, and a title and description among others.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation for using the dialogs to share open graph stories:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#open-graph